# Panel transparency?

Tags: wingpanel

Anytime I change the desktop background the panel transparency changes to full transparent for any range of colors other than the default background it ships with.. this leads to hard to read text. Thanks

Comment: ok,after the latest update wingpanel does not become fully transparent. is it intentional? if so, can I change it back to the old ways? (It really stood out from other distros)

Answer (score 4):

In System Settings -> Desktop -> Appearance there is a Panel translucency switch which can turn off the panel transparency.

Comment: Doesn't work for the theme I have applied